# Calling super in overriden scope defined in concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm looking to chain an additional query onto a scope in a model. The scope is defined in a concern.

```
module Companyable
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
        scope :for_company, ->(id) {
            where(:company_id => id)
        }
    end
end


class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Companyable

    # I'd like to be able to do something like this:
    scope :for_company, ->(id) {
        super(id).where.not(:status => 'cancelled')
    }
end
```

However, that understandably throws a `NameError: undefined method 'for_company' for class 'Order'`

Comment: did you ever find a way to do this?

Comment: @sixty4bit sorry, no

Comment: ok, I was wrestling with this earlier when I came across your question. I've posted what I came up with in case it's helpful to you.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution I came up with in my case:

Rather than `scope`, just go with a regular class method since `scope` is just "syntactic sugar" for a class method. This is easier to deal with when you need to override using `super`. In your case it would look like this:

```
module Companyable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def for_company(id)
      where(:company_id => id)
    end
  end
end



class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Companyable

  def self.for_company(id)
    super(id).where.not(:status => 'cancelled')
  end
end
```